# Multiple instances of checkbox selection

Tags: jquery

I am not sure if the title is right for this, or my explanation. I hope you understand what I am trying to do when you see the example fiddle. https://jsfiddle.net/bg3045rs/

The javascript code that I use is like this:

```
$("#checkAll").click(function(){
    $('input:checkbox').not(this).prop('checked', this.checked)
    .trigger("change");
});

$(".selector").on("change", function() {
  var parent = $(this).closest("form");

  $("#" + parent.data("checktable"))
    .find('[dbval="' + this.name + '"]')
    .toggleClass("highlight", $(this).is(":checked"));
  parent
    .find(".all")
    .prop(
      "checked",
      parent.find(".selector:checked").length === parent.find(".selector").length
    );
});

$(".all").on("change", function() {
  $(this).closest("form").find(".selector")
    .prop("checked", $(this).is(":checked"))
    .trigger("change");
});

$(".all:checked").each(function() {
  $(this).closest("form").find(".selector").prop("checked", true).trigger("change");
});

$(".selector").trigger("change");
```

Mind you that I didn't write this code. It works perfectly though, I couldn't make a small adjustment. As seen in the example fiddle, When I tried to make a Select All(table 1&2) and Select All(table 3&4) separately, I failed. I'd like an expert touch on the code, what change should make so I can achieve selective highlighting here. Please ask if anything is not clear.Thanks in advance!

Comment: you need something like https://jsfiddle.net/bg3045rs/16/

Comment: yes, this is what I'm trying to do. I didn't examine your code. can I use your method for more instances?

Comment: yes you can do that

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change your input to

```
<input type="checkbox"  name="CheckAll" class="checkAll" class="all" data-form="#form1,#form2">
      All (Table 1&2)</label>
```

and your js to:

```
$(".checkAll").click(function(){
    $($(this).attr('data-form')).find('input:checkbox').not(this).prop('checked', this.checked)
    .trigger("change");
});
```

I created a custom attribute where i store the ids of the forms that you need to toggle, after that i altered the click function to toggle the state only for the forms in the data attribute

Comment: Thanks a lot, I will do it. I will accept your answer when the time limit is up.

Comment: If it is not too much, can I ask you a question, please? Is it possible to make your code work without changing the html ?

Comment: is it possible that you shared the wrong fiddle with me? because in that fiddle you have data-form="#form1,#form2" in the html which is not present in the original html.

Comment: the js in the fiddle is the key, if you put it in the fiddle you provided it will work with your html form there

Comment: yes, the code has jquery 3.3.1 in the fiddle. that's what you mean? https://jsfiddle.net/679x5yz4/  the first part works actually. but there is a problem in the second part (tables).

Comment: thanks a lot.  I don't know what you did, but i'll check it, everything looked same to me before.